# Trying to style data rendered from my DB with styled components and getting Invalid hook call error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, mern

So I'm trying to style data from my rendered react components and have the following Issue.

I think my issue is "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:" but I'm unable to fix this.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ButtonUnstyled from '@mui/base/ButtonUnstyled';
// import { Title } from '../MainElements';
const API_BASE = "http://localhost:3001";


export const RocketCard = () => {
  const [rockets, setRockets] = useState([{
    name: '',
    id: ''
  }])

  useEffect(() => {
      fetch(API_BASE + '/rockets')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setRockets(data))
        .catch((err) => console.error("Error: ", err));
    },[])


  return ( <div className="container">
  
    <Title>Test</Title>
    {rockets.map(rocket =>
    <div className="rocket" key={rocket._id} >
      <h1>{rocket.name}</h1>
    </div>
    )}
  </div>
);

}

const Title = styled.h1`
display: flex;
align-items: center;
line-height: 1.2;
`;
```

[Console Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LpyV.png)

Comment: Thank you, Phil, fixed this. Do you have a solution for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't changed the code,

I'm getting the error as seen below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LpyV.png

Comment: When I said "fixed this" I meant I have stopped the infinite loop thanks to your suggestion. But the original problem still exists.

Code updated

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-stallman-z4fw1?file=/src/App.tsx. What versions of React and styled-components are you using?

Comment: React 17.0.2 and styled-components 5.3.3

Comment: Same as the sandbox. Sorry, can't help any further as the problem cannot be reproduced with the current information

Comment: I understand, thanks for your help. I will try to find a solution based of the sandbox you have created.

Comment: Yep, strip it back to as small a problem as possible. FYI, I think you'd be better off starting your `rockets` state with an empty array, eg `useState([])` instead of a single, placeholder element

Comment: Still struggling, I should add that I'm trying to render this as a component.